# Salvar token que vem no response da Api

Tags: laravel, ionic2, angular

Estou tentando salvar o token que meu servidor envia em cada requisição. Embora, aparentemente, o "Authorization" esteja presente na response, não consigo imprimir o valor.

O código é:
[image: código no service]

O que retorna do servidor:
[image: retorno do servidor]

O que consigo imprimir no console:
[image: console]

No servidor estou usando um middleware para cors
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como consigo "pegar" o token que está vindo no Header Authorization?

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido.
Inseri mais algumas opções no arquivo que gera a response final no server e funcionou. 
Segui a sugestão de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43622368/save-token-that-comes-in-response-to-api

> it looks that you did not expose the header correctly, the browser
>   will not forward this header to your code unless you specify it server
>   side.
>
> try adding this this to you $headers object

```
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization');
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Authorization');
$response->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $newToken);

return $response;
```